# tableToGrid & knockoutjs

Tags: jqgrid, knockout.js

I'm having a pb with jqgrid used with knockoutjs.
I have an HTML table witch contains checkboxes binded using konckoutjs that works fine,
but when i fired the tableToGrid function of JQGRID, my checkboxes lose their binding.

Thanks

JS

```
 var listuserProfile = [];
 var viewModel = {
     userProfile: ko.observableArray(listuserProfile)
};

$(document).ready(function () {               
    //Fire knockoutjs
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

    //Init the user profiles list
    viewModel.userProfile(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.UserProfiles)));

    tableToGrid("#userProfiles");


});
```

HTML

```
 <table id="userProfiles">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>User</th>
                    <th>Admin</th>
                    <th>Manager</th>
                    <th>ADV</th>
                    <th>HR</th>
                    <th>DG</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: userProfile">
                <tr>
                    <td><span data-bind="text: User"></span></td>
                    <td><input disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: Admin" /></td>
                    <td><input disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: Manager" /></td>
                    <td><input disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: ADV" /></td>
                    <td><input disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: HR" /></td>
                    <td><input disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: DG" /></td>                
                </tr>            
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

without the call of the tabletogrid it works fine!!!

Comment: Please add some code to your post! A small jsfiddle which demonstrates your problem would been even more helpful to us to help you with your problem. Without any code there can be 100 reasons to think why your code is not working.

Comment: There is a native KO grid that works very well
https://github.com/ericmbarnard/KoGrid

Comment: I added a sample code,  please check my post